# Dúvida sobre controle textbox Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, userform

Galera, boa noite!
Motivo da minha vinda aqui: Tenho um controle Textbox em um Formulário (VBA) do Excel. Esse formulário está configurado para aceitar quebras de linha com o ENTER e multiline. Porém ao enviar essas informações para um controle javascript ele não aceita as quebras de linha que estão no textbox. Simplesmente ele envia linha/linha que possuo no controle.
Alguém já passou por isso? Sabe como contornar?

Por ex.: Eu digito isso no meu textbox:

[image]

E o retorno que tenho é esse mesmo conteúdo, porém linha a linha e não como um texto único com quebras de linha. Deu pra sacar? Preciso que esse texto seja apenas 1, aceitando as quebras de linha.

Comment: Quando você diz que vai linha por linha, você quer dizer que é passada uma array com as linhas?

Comment: Crie uma rotina que vai ler todas as linhas do seu textbox e vá concatenando elas da forma mais básica possível mesmo, através do "+" entre as strings. Sem ver o seu código fica impossível ajudar mais do que isso